# How can I refactor a program with a large amount of std::cin and std::cout operations?

Tags: c++

This is my code, I don't really like it and I know it can be improved but I just don't know how. How can I refactor this program in terms of the many `std::cin` and `std::cout` operations over each other on each line? Is there any STL library magic that can be done to improve this? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

   int grade;

   std::cout << "Enter the grade you recieved: ";
   std::cin >> grade;
   std::cout << grade << "\n\n";

   if (grade == 100) {
      std::cout << "You got a perfect score!\n";
   } else if (grade > 90 && grade < 100) {
      std::cout << "You got an A\n";
   }

   if (grade == 100) {
      std::cout << "Grade: A+";
   } else if (grade > 90 && grade < 100) {
      std::cout << "Grade : A";
   } else if (grade > 80 && grade < 90) {
      std::cout << "Grade: B";
   } else if (grade > 70 && grade < 80) {
      std::cout << "Grade: C";
   } else if (grade > 60 && grade < 70) {
      std::cout << "Grade: D";
   } else if (grade < 60) {
      std::cout << "Grade: F";
   }

}
```

To make it clear, I'm wanting to improve this code because it seems very un-idiomaitc to use all these if statements and print functions. How can I take advantage of the STL or template functions/classes to refactor this? C++11 is also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Better suited for code review.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for a code-review site than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since we are critiquing code, I should mention that you haven't covered all cases in your conditionals. You won't get a letter grade if you have a score of 90, 80, 70, or 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string GetGrade(int grade);

cout<<GetGrade(grade);
```

Is one way to go to clean up stuff. Basically move all the `if`s into the GetGrade function and call `cout` once.

Once inside GetGrade, you can use an array of the below and do away with the `if`s in favour of a loop.

```
struct Grade{
    int start,end;
    std::string gradeStr;
};
```

Comment: +1, also there is no need to tell the user what was input before, since by default inputs are also shown in the terminal (i.e. the `std::cout << grade << "\n\n";` is useless. Even without the extra function, using the if's to update a `std::string` variable and then printing that value would be an improvement.

Answer (score 5):

You've already gotten a couple answers, but I think I'd do it just a little differently still:

```
static char const *grades[] = { "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "C", "B", "A", "A+"};

std::cout << grades[grade/10];
```

[I hope I counted the number of "F"s correctly.]

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int,std::string> grades = {
        {10,"A+"}, {9,"A"}, {8,"B"}, {7,"C"}, {6,"D"}, {5,"F"}
    };
    std::cout << "Input a grade: ";
    int grade;
    std::cin >> grade;
    grade /= 10;
    if(grade <= 5)
        grade = 5;
    std::cout << "Your grade is: " << grades[grade];
}
```

Uses a look up table. Doesn't validate input or anything but it's short.

Comment: +1 The grade is supposed to be an integer but I guess float is okay too.

Comment: Didnt notice that grades were in intervals of 10s, this wont work in other situations right?

Comment: Yeah I hesitated to use floats, so I switched back to ints. @KarthikT no, this wouldn't work if the grades weren't intervals of 10.